# Linking issue of ImGui into an existing project(LNK2019)

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, lnk2019, imgui

I was working an existing opengl project. I wanted to add ImGui to the project and I followed the process as mentioned by adding all the files into the project and including the main headers into the basic.cc(my main file). But on running the command: "cl $(COMMON) basic.cc ../lib/glfw3dll.lib" through a makefile, the error looks like:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <ImGui/imgui.h>
#include <ImGui/imgui_impl_glfw.h>
#include <ImGui/imgui_impl_opengl3.h>
```

```
/out:../bin/basic.exe
basic.obj
../lib/glfw3dll.lib
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct ImGuiContext * __cdecl ImGui::CreateContext(struct ImFontAtlas *)" (?CreateContext@ImGui@@YAPEAUImGuiContext@@PEAUImFontAtlas@@@Z) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct ImGuiIO & __cdecl ImGui::GetIO(void)" (?GetIO@ImGui@@YAAEAUImGuiIO@@XZ) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::NewFrame(void)" (?NewFrame@ImGui@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::Render(void)" (?Render@ImGui@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct ImDrawData * __cdecl ImGui::GetDrawData(void)" (?GetDrawData@ImGui@@YAPEAUImDrawData@@XZ) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::StyleColorsDark(struct ImGuiStyle *)" (?StyleColorsDark@ImGui@@YAXPEAUImGuiStyle@@@Z) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::Begin(char const *,bool *,int)" (?Begin@ImGui@@YA_NPEBDPEA_NH@Z) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::End(void)" (?End@ImGui@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::Button(char const *,struct ImVec2 const &)" (?Button@ImGui@@YA_NPEBDAEBUImVec2@@@Z) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::DebugCheckVersionAndDataLayout(char const *,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64)" (?DebugCheckVersionAndDataLayout@ImGui@@YA_NPEBD_K11111@Z) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(struct GLFWwindow *,bool)" (?ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL@@YA_NPEAUGLFWwindow@@_N@Z) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame(void)" (?ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init(char const *)" (?ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init@@YA_NPEBD@Z) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame(void)" (?ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
basic.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(struct ImDrawData *)" (?ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData@@YAXPEAUImDrawData@@@Z) referenced in function main
..\bin\basic.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 15 unresolved externals
```

I am not sure what to do in this kind of error.

Comment: It seems you're not linking with the actual library. You need to update the linker settings in your project settings to add the actual library.

Comment: The instructions  for imgui say you have to add all of the .cpp files to your project. If you are building on the command line you need to list them after your `basic.cc` on your cl command. That is unless `$(COMMON)` is an environment variable with all of these listed.

Comment: Actually, I am new to C++. It will be helpful if you can guide me how to link the library or provide some resources. Thank you in advance.